# Date storing five hours behind or above based on TimeZone

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am using Java DateTime class in my class and my server is present in UTC timezone.

What happens here is when I store any data in date column in my table for example today's date is 14-10-2015 01:00:00 AM, in database it's storing as 14-10-2015 06:00:00 AM(from IST), If I do in my CST time it's going as 14-10-2015 07:30:00 PM.

How to store the same time in database don't mind whatever the Timezone it is.

There is no code to support because just I am using DateTime date = new DateTime();
And converting date.toDate() and persisting.

Comment: Does this happen locally, or is this an occurrence in production?

Comment: @Makoto : Local I don't have any problem only in production.

Comment: You should Store all datetime in db as UTC time.
Convert date while retrieving from db.

Comment: @Karthik What database? What data type is the database column? Show us a short code example.

Answer (score 1):

java.util.Date object always have the UTC value. Whereas Calendar objects are used to handle timezone. You can try like this:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
```